# Send http request to laravel API from android emulator

Tags: android, laravel, android-emulator, httprequest, laragon

I'm creating an android app and want to send http requests to my local website which I'm hosting using laragon.

I'm using laragon and when i run the command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject --prefer-dist
```

the project is created in "C:\laragon\www" in a folder myproject. I can access the page with "myproject.test" locally.

Now I'm unclear on where to send the http request to. I can access the localhost from my android emulator with 10.0.2.2 and when i do "10.0.2.2/myproject" I can see the folder hierarchie from my project. I have a controller called "UserController.php"

```
 class UserController extends Controller
 {
    public function getUsername() {
    return view('user', ['username' => 'bob');
    }
}
```

and a route

```
 Route::get('/user', 'UserController@getUsername');
```

Now i would like to to "10.0.2.2/myproject/user" to get the username but this doesn't work. I'm guessing there is a whole new feature or laravel i don't know about to handle http requests from the outside.

So in short:
I'm trying to create a API to which i can send http requests which retrieve data (from a DB) from my emulator.

I hope this is enough info to work with!